# MiniMagick: Making a png partially opaque/how to use '-evaluate'

Tags: ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, minimagick

I am trying to make a partially opaque png using MiniMagick, but I guess what it really boils down to is the syntax for using '-evaluate'

This works in the terminal:

```
convert input.jpg -alpha on -channel a -evaluate set 25% output.png
```

But I don't quite understand how to turn it into minimagick code

This is (the latest permutation of) what I'm trying:

```
require 'mini_magick'

img = MiniMagick::Image.open('input.jpg')
img.combine_options do |mogrify|
    mogrify.alpha 'on'
    mogrify.channel 'a'
    mogrify.evaluate 'set', '25%'

    puts mogrify.inspect
end
img.write('output.png')
```

The `inspect` output shows that `@args` is `@args=["-alpha", "\"on\"", "-channel", "\"a\"", "-evaluate", "\"set\"", "\"25%\""]`

No error messages, but all I get is an identical copy of input.jpg

Comment: you may want to try setting `mogirfy.evaluate 'set 25%'` as the comma does not do what you think it would

Comment: Yeah, that's what I started with, but then you get this error message: Command ("mogrify -alpha "on" -channel "a" -evaluate "set 25%" /var/folders/wh/2k_8_pq10xj0w241f6438l_w0000gn/T/mini_magick20121122-25863-u6ysmi.jpg") failed: {:status_code=>1, :output=>"mogrify: option requires an argument `-evaluate' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/4539.\n"} (MiniMagick::Error)

Comment: Did you try also setting the format as PNG?

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty much all the way there except that you also need to let minimagick know that you are outputting in PNG format using:

```
    img.format('png')
```

Try this instead:

```
    require 'mini_magick'

    img = MiniMagick::Image.open('input.jpg')
    img.format('png')
    img.combine_options do |mogrify|
        mogrify.alpha 'on'
        mogrify.channel 'a'
        mogrify.evaluate 'set', '25%'
    end
    img.write('output.png')
```